# swift convert string to float

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table:

```
let CTCSStable:[String] = [ "67.0 ", "69.3 ", "71.9 "]
```

I need to convert a selected entry to be a string equal to ten times the numeric value of the entry.

```
var tempCTCSS:String = self.CTCSStable[ctcssIndex]
let tempCTCSSF:Float = Float(tempCTCSS)!
```

This throws an exception:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting the crash is because `Float(tempCTCSS)!` is trying to convert `tempCTCSS` into a Float, but it fails, and then you force unwrap that value and it is nil, so it crashes.

1. The reason why it fails to convert that string to a Float is because there is white space. Try removing the spaces.
2. I would never force unwrap (i.e. `!`) unless you know that that value is there. The best practice would be to wrap that value in an `if let` statement. That conditionally unwraps the value and prevents the crash