# Float conversion crash

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion

I have this :

```
let value = data[1]   // its a string
print("val:",value)   // prints 28.3  
let a:Float = Float(value)!
print("a:",a)
```

Which prints `a` ok till sometimes crashes where `value` **has a value on it**

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I can put the `question mark` to mark it as optional, but I am trying to understand how it crashes when **there is a value** .

Comment: What string causes it to crash?

Comment: The conversion of value to a . After the crash I can put the arrow on it and see it has a value of 28.3 .

Comment: Perhaps there is a leading or trailing space, newline or other whitespace in the string?

Comment: Oh thats possible ! since it coming from hardware. Thanks Martin. So how can I solve that ,to make the conversion anyway ? ( there is perhaps a new line/carrier return at the end)

Comment: You can "trim" the string first. – Or use NSNumberFormatter, that tolerates whitespace, if I remember correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354256/swift-convert-string-to-float

Comment: Thanks a lot. You where right, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use optional wrapping with `if let`.

```
if let a = value as? Float {
     print("a:%f",a)
}
```

To remove space try like this

```
let newValue = value.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

**Swift 3**

```
let newValue = value.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

Comment: Thanks I know that, but why it crashes with a value ??

Comment: On the line of the conversion from value to a. (where value has a value in it according to the debugger)

Comment: @Curnelious No, What I am asking is when it is crashing what is the value of variable value?

Comment: value= 28.3  . Thanks.

Comment: Thats true, he probably is contain. Your solution solves this ?